# if else statement with two condition

Tags: java, if-statement

This maybe trivial but I have this code

```
if(condition 1 & condition 2){
// apply some code
}
else{
// apply other code
}
```

my question is: When is else applied?
Is it applied when both conditions are `false` or is it enough for one condition to be `false`?

Comment: This is absolutely trivial to try yourself (or just look up the documentation...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you are using [bitwise and](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) which I don't think does what you want.

In order to use logical and (`&&`) change `if(condition 1 & condition 2){` to `if(condition 1 && condition 2){`.

Secondly, if one condition is `false` then the else will evaluate.

When using `&&` in if statements the if logic evaluates if and only if both sides of the `&&` evaluate to true.

if evaluates when:

```
true && true
```

else evaluates when:

```
false && true
true && false
false && false
```

Comment: In java `&` will work any place that `&&` works (as `boolean & boolean -> boolean`), given the difference that it will eagerly evaluate both expressions. That is, *`&` is only bitwise when applied to an integral type* such a long or int: `integraltype & integraltype -> widendedintegraltype`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I think it's still a relevant point considering OP did just put `condition 1` and `condition 2` without indicating the variable type. It may work in this case, and it may not. If the OP is new enough to programming to be working on figuring out if statements though, it's safe to say that there may be some difficulty figuring out why `&` is behaving oddly.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry, didn't understand correctly. So if `condition1` is `false`, with `&&` will go to `else` here? and `&` will check both unconditionally? If this the case, in which scenarios do an `&` is useful to use if you know that will be false even if I evaluate `condition2`?

Comment: That is correct: `&` forces both expressions to be evaluated (as there is *no* 'short-circuit' behavior). However the result (barring side-effects of the second expression) are the same; in some cases this is desirable but it usually is not which is why `&&` should be preferred - the short-circuiting logical-AND `&&` form also allows chained checks like `x != null && x.y == z` . (A side-effect in a condition, which may warrant a 'clever' `&`, usually indicates a design that can be improved.)

Comment: "..However the result (barring side-effects *and dependencies* of the second expression) are the same.."

Answer (score 1):

You will need a little logic here. Check the Truth table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

if`(condition 1 && condition 2){` will enter the else if the condition of the if `(condition 1 && condition 2)` is false. So the condition is false if:

> ```
> condition 1 is false 
> OR
> condition 2 is false
> ```

In that case, it's the else block that will be executed.

Also, check the difference between bitwise operators since && and & are not the same thing.